# Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for uuid: "test"

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 3.2 with doctrine and postgresql.

I've created an entity with a `uuid` as primary key.

My entity definition:

```
/**
 * Booking
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="booking")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BookingRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"AppBundle\EventListener\BookingListener"})
 */
class Booking {
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

In my controller I have a show action like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("booking/{id}", name="booking_show")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, Booking $booking) {
  ...
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, but when I try to load a route putting an wrong value as an ID (i.e. `/booking/hello123`), I receive a:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for uuid: "hello123"
```

Instead I would expect a 404.

Is there a way to capture this exception and redirect to a 404 page?

Comment: You could try with a more specific routing, i.e. `@Route("/booking/{id}", name="booking_show", requirements={"id": "[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}(-?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}){7}"})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [Route Requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html) - you can specify what conditions your parameter need to match to "qualify" to a certain route. This requirement is a regex, so all you need to do is to write a regex for an UUID

```
/**
 * @Route("booking/{id}", name="booking_show", requirements={"id": "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}"})
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, Booking $booking) {
  ...
}
```

NOTE: Regex used above is just first result I found in Google for UUID regex, I didn't verify if it works

In the end if your id does not match regex, it does not match route and you should get 404.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the showaction

```
/**
 * @Route("booking/{id}", name="booking_show")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function showAction(Request $request,$bookingID) {
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $booking = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entity')->find(bookingID);
  if(!$booking)
    $this->createNotFoundException('No entity found with id  :'.$bookingID);
  ...
}
```

Comment: this actually won't work: `find` method throws exception when `bookingId` is not a valid `UUID`

Comment: try to  add a verification of the uuid

function isValidUuid( $uuid ) {
    
    if (!is_string($uuid) || (preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/', $uuid) !== 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}